# Transpose data from column to row in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have many text file Data, and I selected my data from the text and  inserted it into one Excel File, but I have one problem:
Data exported in the column, Like below:

```
David
1253.2500
2568.000
8566.236 
Jack
3569.00
5269.22
4586.00
```

But I want to output the data in rows, like the one below:

```
David 1253.2500 2568.000 8566.236
Jack 3569.00 5269.22 4586.00
```

Code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
while True:
path = input("Insert location:")
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
df_list = []
for file in file_list:
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df_list.append(df.take([0,-1,-4,-7]))
excl_merged = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=False)
#part two of the code
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Total.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
excl_merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False)
writer.close()
print('success!!')
```

I have tested many methods, but they did not work; for example, I tested

```
pandas.transpose()
```

I tried to do this in Excel, But it did not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['David', '1253.2500', '2568.000', '8566.236', 'Jack', '3569.00', '5269.22', '4586.00']})
```

You can use:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
m = s.isna()

out = (df
   .assign(col=df['col'].where(m).ffill(),
           value=s, index=m.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount())
   .loc[~m]
   .pivot(index='index', columns='col', values='value')
  )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
col       David     Jack
index                   
1      1253.250  3569.00
2      2568.000  5269.22
3      8566.236  4586.00
```